# AWS AutoScaling 'oldestinstance' Termination Policy does not always terminate oldest instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

## Scenario

I am creating a script that will launch new instances into an AutoScaling Group and then remove the old instances. The purpose is to introduce newly created (or updated) AMI's to the AutoScaling Group. This is accomplished by increasing the `Desired` capacity by double the current number of instances. Then, after the new instances are `Running`, decreasing the `Desired` capacity by the same number.

## Problem

When I run the script, I watch the group capacity increase by double, the new instances come online, they reach the `Running` state, and then the group capacity is decreased. Works like a charm. The problem is that SOMETIMES the instances that are terminated by the decrease are actually the new ones instead of the older ones.

## Question

How can I ensure that the AutoScaling Group will always terminate the Oldest Instance?

## Settings

- The AutoScaling Group has the following `Termination Polices`: OldestInstance, OldestLaunchConfiguration. The `Default` policy has been removed.
- The `Default Cooldown` is set to 0 seconds.
- The Group only has one Availability Zone.

## Troubleshooting

- I played around with the `Cooldown` setting. Ended up just putting it on 0.
- I waited different lengths of time to see if the existing servers needed to be running for a certain amount of time before they would be terminated. It seems that if they are less than 5 minutes old, they are less likely to be terminated, but not always. I had servers that were 20 minutes old that were not terminated instead of the new ones. Perhaps newly launched instances have some termination protection grace period?

## Concession

I know that in most cases, the servers I will be replacing will have been running for a long time. In production, this might not be an issue. Still, it is possible that during the normal course of AutoScaling, an older server will be left running instead of a newer one. This is not an acceptable way to operate.

I could force specific instances to terminate, but that would defeat the point of the `OldestInstance` Termination Policy.

**Update**: 12 Feb 2014
I have continued to see this in production. Instances with older launch configs that have been running for weeks will be left running while newer instances will be terminated. At this point I am considering this to be a bug. A [thread at Amazon](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=523370) was opened for this topic a couple years ago, apparently without resolution.

**Update**: 21 Feb 2014
I have been working with AWS support staff and at this point they have preliminarily confirmed it could be a bug. They are researching the problem.

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like you can, precisely, because auto-scaling is trying to do one other thing for you in addition to having the correct number of instances running: keep your instance counts balanced across availability zones... and it prioritizes this consideration higher than your termination policy.

> Before Auto Scaling selects an instance to terminate, it first identifies the Availability Zone that has more instances than the other Availability Zones used by the group. If all Availability Zones have the same number of instances, it identifies a random Availability Zone. Within the identified Availability Zone, Auto Scaling uses the termination policy to select the instance for termination.
>
> — http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/us-termination-policy.html

If you're out of balance, then staying in balance is arguably the most sensible strategy, especially if you are using ELB.  The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_AddAvailabilityZone.html) is a little ambiguous, but ELB will advertise one public IP in the DNS for each availability zone where it is configured; these three IP addresses will achieve the first tier of load balancing by virtue of round-robin DNS.  If all of the availability zones where the ELB is enabled have healthy instances, then there appears to be a 1:1 correlation between which external IP the traffic hits and which availability zone's servers that traffic will be offered to by ELB -- at least that is what my server logs show.  It *appears* that ELB doesn't route traffic across availability zones to alternate servers unless all of the servers in a given zone are detected as unhealthy, and that may be one of the justifications of why they've implemented autoscaling this way.

Although this algorithm might not always kill the oldest instance first on a region-wide basis, if it does operate as documented, it would kill off the oldest one in the selected availability zone, and at some point it should end up cycling through all of them over the course of several shifts in load... so it would not leave the oldest running indefinitely, either.  The larger the number of instances in the group is, it seems like the less significant this effect should be.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I actually considered the availability zone. However in my case, I am only use one zone, so I would assume that this would not apply.

Comment: Are you 100% sure your auto scaling group isn't set to use all availability zones?  I was seeing exactly the behaviour your question described, and changing to a single availability zone seems to have fixed it. I've done a half dozen rolling deploys now, and it's reliably terminating the oldest instance. Previously, at least every other time it was terminating the new instance. It seems like "OldestInstance" may actually consider availability zones, contrary to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of other ways to do it:

1. Increase desired to 2x
2. Wait for action to increase capacity
3. When the new instances are running, suspend all AS activity (as-suspend-processes MyAutoScalingGroup)
4. Reset desired
5. Terminate old instances
6. Resume AS activity.

Or:

1. Bring up a brand new ASG with the new launch config.
2. Suspend AS activity , until 1. is finished.
3. If everything is ok, delete the old ASG.
4. Resume AS activity

For ultimate rollback deployment:

1. Create new ELB (might have to ask Amazon to provision more elb if you have a lot of traffic, this is kinda lame and makes it not automation friendly)
2. Create new ASG with new LC
3. Switch DNS to new ELB
4. Delete old ELB/ASG/LC if everything's fine, if not just change DNS back

Or with the new ASG API that lets you attach/detach instances from ASG:

1. Somehow bring up your new instances (could just be run-instances or create a temp asg)
2. Suspend AS activity, Use http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/attach-instance-asg.html to attach them to your old ASG,
3. Use http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/detach-instance-asg.html or terminate your old instances
4. Resume AS activity

The reason you might want to use your old ASG is because it can be a pita to set all the policies again (even when automated) and it feels a bit safer to change as little as possible.

A.

Answer (score 0):

My use case is that we needed to scale down and be able to choose which machines go down.  Unfortunately the termination policy "OldestFirst" was not working for us either.  I was able to use a variant of the attach/detach method that ambakshi shared to remove the oldest (or any instance I choose) and at the same time lower the desired instances value of the autoscaling group.

Step 1 – Change the autoscaling group Min value to the number you want to scale down to.

Step 2 – Suspend the ASG

Step 3 – Detach the instances you want to terminate, you can do multiple instances in one command.  Make sure to use the should-decrement-desired-capacity flag

Step 4 – Resume the ASG

Step 5 – Terminate your instances using the console or the CLI

**UPDATE**

There is no need to suspend the Auto Scaling Group, just doing steps 1, 3 and 5 worked for me.  Just be aware of any availability zone balancing that may happen.